# The Diophantine equation $x^p - 4y^p = z^2$ with $(x, y) = 1$ and $x, y, z > p.$

Tags: diophantine-equations

If $p \geq 5$ is a prime, are there any integers $x, y, z > p$ such that
$(x, y) = 1$ 
and
$$x^{p} - 4y^{p} = z^{2}$$

Comment: There's $5^3-4\cdot 1^3=11^2$ ...

Comment: Hi thanks. It reminds me to put the condition $x, y, z > p.$

Comment: See http://mathoverflow.net/questions/178906/the-diophantine-equation-xp-4yp-z2.

Comment: @Dietrich Burde  Yes, thank you. It is I who asked the same question in MatheOverflow.

Comment: All right, very good. So there is a literature on this problem. I was looking for this article of Bennett and Skinner, but could not find it. Is there a reference for $p=3$ somewhere ?

Comment: Cohen has treated the equation $x^3-2y^3=z^2$ in his book on Diophantine equations.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This equation is a special case of the generalized Fermat equation
$$
Ax^p+By^q=Cz^r
$$
for $A=C=1$, $B=-4$ and $p=q$, $r=2$. We have $\frac{1}{p}+\frac{1}{q}+\frac{1}{r}<1$
in our case $(p,q,r)=(p,p,2)$ for $p>3$, so that we are in the hyperbolic case. Hence for $p>3$ there are at most finitely many coprime solutions $(x,y,z)$ by the Darmon-Granville theorem.
And probably there are very few such solutions - the abc-conjecture implies that there are at most $2$ solutions once $n>n_0$, independent of $A,B,C$.
The equation is not hyperbolic for $p=3$, but the argument with the abc-conjecture still applies. There is a large literature on the generalized Fermat equation, which will be helpful to study this case (the experts might know more).

Edit: A reference was given afterwards [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/178906/the-diophantine-equation-xp-4yp-z2), and Gerry Myerson found $78^3-4\cdot 29^3=614^2$ and $93^3-4\cdot 53^3=457^2$for $p=3$.

Comment: (Maple and) I found 8 examples of $x^3-4y^3=z^2$ with $\gcd(x,y)=1$ and $x<1000$.